# OpenSSL EVP_DigestSignFinal segfault

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, openssl, sign

I'm trying to sign a message using the OpenSSL C api.  The following code segfaults because of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` during either of the calls to `EVP_DigestSignFinal`.  I'm using OpenSSL 1.0.1g.  I tried switching from the newer `DigestSign*` functions to the older `Sign*` functions, and it still segfaults.

`private_key` is set with `EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA` from an RSA key loaded from a PEM file.  The first call to `EVP_DigestSignFinal` fills `s_len` with the maximum possible length of the signature for the signing algorithm, so `signature` not being big enough shouldn't be the issue, and the second call writes to the signature buffer and fills `s_len` with the length of the signature.

I would appreciate any help I could get with this.

```
vector<unsigned char> rsa_sha512_sign(
        const vector<unsigned char>& document, 
        shared_ptr<EVP_PKEY> private_key) {
    EVP_MD_CTX* md;
    if (!(md = EVP_MD_CTX_create())) {
        throw runtime_error("Error initializing ENV_MD_CTX.");
    }

    if (EVP_DigestSignInit(md, NULL, EVP_sha512(), NULL, private_key.get()) 
            != 1) {
        throw runtime_error("Error in EVP_DigestSignInit.");
    }

    if (EVP_DigestSignUpdate(md, document.data(), document.size()) != 1) {
        throw runtime_error("Error computing hash on document.");
    }
    size_t s_len;
    if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(md, NULL, &s_len) != 1) { // Segfault here
        throw runtime_error("Error determining maximum signature size.");
    }

    vector<unsigned char> signature(s_len);
    if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(md, signature.data(), &s_len) != 1) { // or here (or both)
        throw runtime_error("Error signing document.");
    }
    signature.resize(s_len);
    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(md);
    return move(signature);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely with how you are initializing `private_key`. Probably, you are mixing `malloc()` with `delete`, and corrupting the heap in the process. You need to provide `shared_ptr` the proper deleter for the pointer you feed to it if the pointer was not created with `new`.

```
    shared_ptr<RSA> r(RSA_new(), RSA_free);
    shared_ptr<EVP_PKEY> p(EVP_PKEY_new(), EVP_PKEY_free);
    shared_ptr<BIGNUM> bn(BN_new(), BN_free);
    vector<unsigned char> doc(0, 100);

    BN_set_word(bn.get(), RSA_F4);
    RSA_generate_key_ex(r.get(), 2048, bn.get(), 0);
    EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(p.get(), r.get());
    rsa_sha512_sign(doc, p);
```

Comment: `EVP_MD_CTX_create` initializes `md` (The [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_DigestInit.html#DESCRIPTION)).  Also, I added it just to be 100% sure, and it still segfaults in the same place.

Comment: Apologies for not noticing that. Your code works for me. Please check how you use `shared_ptr`. Use `valgrind` to see if it identifies a culprit for you.

Comment: That fixed it.  I had no idea that you couldn't do that, thanks!  I accepted your answer, but I can't upvote you yet.